# Spring Integration webservice outbound gateway - capturing request and response to DB with additional values

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-integration

I am using Spring integration WS 2.2 outbound gateway to invoke a webservice.
One of our requirement is to capture the soap request and response xmls to the database in addition to some other values like transaction id etc.
If i use ClientInterceptor to save the request/response to DB, it only has access to the soap request and the response but not to the values like transaction Id. So is there a way to retrieve and return the soap request and response from the interceptor OR a way to pass custom values to the interceptor?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `transactionId`?

Comment: I have an object ServiceRequest with serviceRequestMessage, transactionId and few other additional properties. From one of my custom class I take the serviceRequestMessage from the serviceRequest object and pass it to the outbound gateway which will be marshalled and sent as the soap request.

Comment: If these are extra (out-of-band) properties, not in the SOAP message, you would have to use some kind of holder class (most likely with a `ThreadLocal`) to make them available to a custom interceptor.